# AWS Elastic search service - IAM Role (Refresh session token - Node.js)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I'm using AWS Elastic search service and written a Node.js wrapper (runs within a ECS dockerized container) . IAM roles are used to create a singleton connection with Elastic search.

I'm trying to refresh my session token by checking AWS.config.credentials.needsRefresh() before every request - however it always returns true even after the session has expired. Obviously AWS is complaining with a 403 error. Any ideas will be greatly appreciated .

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var config = require('config');
var connectionClass = require('http-aws-es');
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

AWS.config.getCredentials(function() {     

    AWS.config.update({
      credentials: new AWS.Credentials(AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken),
      region: 'us-east-1'
    });
  }


)

    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: `${config.get('elasticSearch.host')}`,
      log: 'debug',
      connectionClass: connectionClass,
      amazonES: {
        credentials: new AWS.EnvironmentCredentials('AWS')
      }

    });


module.exports = client;
```

Comment: The SDK should be doing this for you automatically.  You may be doing something incorrectly that is preventing it.  Show us the code you're using for the "singleton connection."

Comment: I have updated my code in my question - IAM role is passed to the EC2 instance running within ECS - AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken is passed which eventually expires